# How to use jar with embedded .so file in OSGI

Tags: java, jar, osgi

I am trying to make an OSGI bundle but am running into trouble because of one of my dependencies.

I am making an application that does some serial IO and GPIO stuff on a Beaglebone Black. For the serial and GPIO I am using the library [libbulldog](https://github.com/SilverThings/bulldog). One of the jar files of the library contains native code in a .so file.

I wrap the libbulldog library using bnd-platform to make an OSGI bundle from it.

If I use this approach I get an exception when trying the run the application in Apache Felix:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at test.BBB.core.BSSerial.setup_port(BSSerial.java:215)
    at test.BBB.core.BSSerial.<init>(BSSerial.java:28)
    at test.BBB.Activator.start(Activator.java:50)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2226)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2144)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.silverspoon.bulldog.core.platform.IncompatiblePlatformException
    at io.silverspoon.bulldog.core.platform.Platform.createBoard(Unknown Source)
    at test.bs.sys.Setup.<clinit>(Setup.java:22)
```

Using the library outside of an OSGI context gives no problems, but it seems I need to do something extra to make the .so file accessible when used in with OSGI bundles?

The dependency jar in question looks like this:

```
|-META-INF
|  |- metadata
|
|-io.silverspoon.bulldog.beagleboneblack
|  |- Java code
|
|-lib
   |- bulldog-linux-native.beagleboneblack.so
```

What should be done to make the embedded .so file usable in an OSGI context?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an appropriate `Bundle-NativeCode` header to the manifest of the bundle containing the .so and System.loadLibrary call.